# How to decrypt string with AES256 in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, string

I have encrypted string "I am a good boy" with key "1234",and I wanna decrypt it. Here is my code, but it finally outputs "NULL" but not "I am a good boy". How can I get a correct result?

```
NSString *content = @"VvHjCwHUjIgZOiYlncPWEoX/UInS7ZNbC4sy8ESa/fM=";

NSData *contentData = [content dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSUInteger dataLength = contentData.length;

NSString *key = @"1234";

char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES256+1];
bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr));
[key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);
size_t numBytesDecrypted = 0;
CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128,
                                      kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                      keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                      NULL,
                                      contentData.bytes, dataLength,
                                      buffer, bufferSize,
                                      &numBytesDecrypted);
if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
    NSData *result = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesDecrypted];
    if(result) {
        NSString * string = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:result encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"%@",string);
    }
}else {
    free(buffer);
}
```

Comment: 1. Q of type "why isn't that code working"  are out of scope of SO. 2. At least: What is your specific Q? Error messages? Wrong result? Which? Expected result?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My question is why it returns NULL instead of "I am a good boy"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data looks like it's base64 encoded. You should decode it like this:

```
NSData *contentData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:content options:0];
```